# Multiple applications sharing common EJB JAR in TomEE

Tags: java, ejb, openejb, apache-tomee

I have an EJB jar `DetailsLookup.jar` which needs to be shared by two consumer applications - `VehicleMake.war` and `VehicleModel.war`

I have placed the EJB jar file under `<catalina_base>/lib` and both the war file under `<catalina_base>/webapps`

When I deploy only one of the WAR files, the deployment is successful, but with 2 WAR files I get the error as below. It seems, TomEE is trying to deploy the EJB for every consumer application instead of deploying it only once

```
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.DuplicateDeploymentIdException: Application cannot be deployed as it contains deployment-ids which are in use: app: D:\apache-tomcat\instance1\webapps\VehicleModel
    DetailsLookup
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:790)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:756)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1308)
    ... 32 more
```

I have also noticed that when I deploy only `VehicleMake.war`, the JNDI name for my EJB has the application context path also appended (which says that the EJB is deployed per project and not common)

**Expected JNDI name:**

> global/DetailsLookup!com.my.company.details.service.DetailsLookup

**Actual JNDI name:**

> global/**VehicleMake**/DetailsLookup!com.my.company.details.service.DetailsLookup

Can anyone help me to identify what the issue is with deploying EJB and if I need to change any configurations to deploy it as a common EJB instead of application specific?

Comment: This is why we have EAR files. Put both WARs and the EJB jar in an EAR file and then it will be shared.

Comment: Hi @SteveC, Thanks for your reply. I am migrating to 'Tomcat' from 'JBoss' and 'JBoss' supports `jar` deployment for `EJB`s. So, wanted to check if there is an option in Tomcat also for that. I know we can deploy EARs, but wanted to avoid it if there is an option for deploying `EJB`s as `jar` files

Comment: The documentation at [Deploying An Application To TomEE Or OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/tomee-8.0/docs/application-deployment-solutions.html) says that all modules (including EJB jars) should be deployed in `<catalina_base>/apps/`. I guess the behaviour anywhere else will be undefined, particularly regarding the computation of JNDI names.

Answer (score 1):

In `conf/system.properties`, you can change the name of deployed artifacts to avoid collisions.

Try adding this line:

```
openejb.deploymentId.format = {appId}/{ejbJarId}/{ejbName}
```